# Android List to Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a custom List which holds information stored from a online mysql database. I now want to put this List into a sqlite internal database. The table has already been created in the database.  I also have a databasehelper class which is working fine.

All the list information is stored in FoodInfoModel class which is made of get and set properties.

Do I create a method in the databasehelper class to insert the whole list at once? not sure how to go about it.

## Current Method in databasehelper

```
 public void addDiet(FoodInfoModel foodinfomodel) {


SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_DIET_ID, foodinfomodel.getDietID()); 
values.put(KEY_DAY, foodinfomodel.getDay());
values.put(KEY_QTY, foodinfomodel.getQty()); 
values.put(KEY_TIME_FOOD, foodinfomodel.getTime()); 
values.put(KEY_ITEM_FOOD, foodinfomodel.getItem()); 
values.put(KEY_MEASURE, foodinfomodel.getMeasure()); 

// Inserting Row
db.insert("my_diet", null, values);
db.close(); // 
 }
```

## Function to set List and Adapter

```
   public void onFetchComplete(List<FoodInfoModel> data) {

    this.data = data;

    System.out.println("data is " + data);

    if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();

    // create new adapter
     adapter = new DietAdapterNew(this, data);
    // set the adapter to list
  setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listview);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

How do i add that data list to the internal sqlite db?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need one more method.

```
public void addDiet(List<FoodInfoModel> foodinfomodels) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    for( FoodInfoModel foodinfomodel : foodinfomodels ){
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_DIET_ID, foodinfomodel.getDietID()); 
        values.put(KEY_DAY, foodinfomodel.getDay());
        values.put(KEY_QTY, foodinfomodel.getQty()); 
        values.put(KEY_TIME_FOOD, foodinfomodel.getTime()); 
        values.put(KEY_ITEM_FOOD, foodinfomodel.getItem()); 
        values.put(KEY_MEASURE, foodinfomodel.getMeasure()); 

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert("my_diet", null, values);
    }

    db.close(); // 
}
```

Comment: This answer is exactly what i was looking for and works perfectly thank you very much! 10 points!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to create this kind of methods in DatabaseHelper class

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public void insertFoodInfo(ChatBase chat) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_DIET_ID, foodinfomodel.getDietID());
    values.put(KEY_DAY, foodinfomodel.getDay());
    values.put(KEY_QTY, foodinfomodel.getQty());
    values.put(KEY_TIME_FOOD, foodinfomodel.getTime());
    values.put(KEY_ITEM_FOOD, foodinfomodel.getItem());
    values.put(KEY_MEASURE, foodinfomodel.getMeasure());

    db.insert("my_diet", null, values);
    db.close();
}

public void updateFoodInfo(FoodInfoModel  model) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_DIET_ID, foodinfomodel.getDietID());
    values.put(KEY_DAY, foodinfomodel.getDay());
    values.put(KEY_QTY, foodinfomodel.getQty());
    values.put(KEY_TIME_FOOD, foodinfomodel.getTime());
    values.put(KEY_ITEM_FOOD, foodinfomodel.getItem());
    values.put(KEY_MEASURE, foodinfomodel.getMeasure());

    db.update("my_diet", values, KEY_DIET_ID + "=" + model.getId(),null);
    db.close();
}
```

}

and then update or insert each FoodInfoModel inside the loop

And for bulk insert can use this code

```
db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        ...
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
```

Comment: And maybe you can use bulkInsert for performance. so basically you begin a transaction, then loop with inserts through your list and when done, commit the transaction

Answer (score 0):

What you should create is a separate class with `public static` functions that process the CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete) functions associated with the SQL transactions.

Example (SQLcrud.java):

```
public static boolean insertObject(SQLdatabase localDB, Object insertObject)
{
    // Test if things are not null and that the DB is open and writable.

    // Insert the object

    // If insert successful, return TRUE.

    // If anything wrong or insert not successful return FALSE (or int indicating what went wrong.
}
```

Actual Example:

```
public static boolean insertLocalAdr(SQLiteDatabase db, PersonAddress adr, boolean deleteCurrent, boolean transaction)
        throws SQLFunctionFailed {
    if(db != null && adr != null)
    {
        try
        {
            // If the connection is open and writable.
            SQLiteGeneral.openAndWritable(db);

            if(deleteCurrent)
            {
                deleteLocalAdr(db, transaction);
            }

            String sqlStmt = GeneralSQLfunctions.getUserAdrInsert(
                    adr,
                    PersonAddress.ADR_TABLE_NAME,
                    GeneralSQLfunctions.databaseType.SQLITE);

            return StmtExecution(db, sqlStmt, transaction);

        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new SQLFunctionFailed(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new SQLFunctionFailed("Given DB or Adr was NULL! FATAL ERROR!");
    }
}
```

Note: `GeneralSQLfunctions.getUserAdrInsert` just gets a simple formatted INSERT statement and `StmtExecution` simply executes the statement on the SQL DB. They are there for simplification. `SQLiteGeneral.openAndWritable(db)` throws a (custom) `SQLFunctionFailed` exception so the function fails and does not proceed.

Answer (score 0):

While iterating over each list items, you can start a new AsyncTask or Thread to to make it faster.